# IOS FacebooSDK 3.0 FBLoginVIew in modal viewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I have modal view controller displayed on rightBarButtonItem click. I'm using FbLoginView in this controller as in sample [ios-Facebook SDK 3.0 Error 5 When Posting Status Update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11850899/ios-facebook-sdk-3-0-error-5-when-posting-status-update).

But i'm unable to show modal view controller more than one time.
 I tried to release FBLoginView on ViewDidUnload but it always crashes on second atempt to open modal view controller.

Answer (score 5):

Got the same problem and deal with it for couple days already. And finally this is my solution:

```
if (!FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
    theLoginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];
    theLoginView.frame = CGRectOffset(theLoginView.frame,
                                      ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width-theLoginView.frame.size.width)/2,
                                      ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-theLoginView.frame.size.height)/2 -50);
    theLoginView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:theLoginView];
    [theLoginView sizeToFit];
}  
//Only close the session when application is terminating, this will save the token information:
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    [FBSession.activeSession close];
}  

//And keep the FBSession within the app until the user want to logout:
[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
```

Right now for me its working completely fine. Hope this help.

Comment: this works perfectly for me as well! In fact it works even if you Log Out in 1 view and Log In in the other, and vice versa! Although I did not really need to close and clear the token information anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

The FB SDK doesn't seem to like you creating more than one FBLoginView.  Maybe you can if you properly terminate the session, but I found it easier just to create the LoginView once and keep it around.

I did this as follows:

1) in my `.m` modal view controller file, I created a static variable

```
static FBLoginView* loginView;
```

2) When loading the modal view controller in my `viewDidLoad`, instead of

```
FBLoginView *loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithPermissions:
                          [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"status_update"]];
loginview.frame = CGRectOffset(loginview.frame, 10, 10);
```

I added a check to find if its already initialized, like this:

```
if (!loginView) {
    loginView = [[FBLoginView alloc] initWithPermissions:
                              [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"status_update"]];
    loginView.frame = CGRectOffset(loginView.frame, 10, 10);

}
```

Beyond that, I just followed the example of FB's HelloFacebook project.

Not pretty code, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Try to add something like this:

```
if(!yourFBLoginView)
{
    yourFBLoginView = [FBLoginView alloc] init...];
}
```

And/or do not forget to close your active session when you dismissing your modalViewController.

```
if ([[FBSession activeSession] isOpen])
{
    [[FBSession activeSession] close];
}
```

Comment: i dont think its wise to close the session when we dismiss the modal since that can logout the user. There has to be another fix or we need to file this under bugs

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer for me (a variant of what was said) was only that I needed to have:

`[FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];`

in the:

`(void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application`

function. The problem specifically for me was, while I was testing...I was constantly terminating the app without actually logging out the user without ever destroying the `FBSession`, so that when I went back into the app to test what I had changed - my Facebook user was still logged in, and thus some of the conditionals were being incorrectly met. I think this is very important for anyone who is testing (and I'm actually thinking that you should have that line in there anyway) to make sure to clear the session every time the application terminates to avoid this problem...I can imagine a scenario where my app just crashed on somebody and now they are reopening it and they experience the crash because the session was never cleared.