# FaceBook like page from my application

Tags: ios, facebook-sdk-3.0

I am working on facebook page like without facebook like button. In my application.

i am using following code to like page from my application.

Following is page url for which i want to add like in Facebook.

```
NSString *likePage=@"https://www.facebook.com/pages/Shaktimantelecom/265306070277816?ref=hl"; // here you page url
```

Following is my `FaceBookRequestConnection` class to like page from my application.

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   likePage, @"object",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"token"],@"access_token",
                                   nil];
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/me/og.likes" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"liked with id %@",[result valueForKey:@"id"]] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        NSLog(@"result is %@",result);
    }];
```

When i use the above code it gives me error as `"The operation couldn't be completed (com.facebook.sdk error 5)"`.

Please help and tell if i am doing any thing wrong.

```
Note: I am using Facebook sdk.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13264711/1059705 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/13496007/1059705  might be helpful

Comment: The `og` in the action name stands for Open Graph - you can only like Open Graph objects (URLs outside of Facebook) with this, not Facebook pages.

Comment: @CBroe i tryed it but now its give me id result as null.